# Specific data import from Excel

Tags: import, excel

I guess this is really mundane question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.
Having a rather complicated Excel that came from testing centre, I need to import specific data into *Mathematica* for further analysis, rows `129` to `159` from column `G` and `M` - this should be in format `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}` - just to be really on point, `x1:=G129, y1:=M129, x2:=G130` and so on.

So I tried many variations on

```
a = Import["....xlsx",{"Data",1,{129,...,159},{7,13}}]
```

where `7` and `13` are numbers of columns `G` and `M` respectively, but it obviously does not work.

Many thanks ahead,

G

**TIP**

The question is answered bellow, however, I stumbled upon the problem of numbering Excel sheets. Then I found out that there is a code for finding sheet number. It's `=SHEET(123)`, if `123` is name of the sheet, or  `=SHEET("apple")` if `apple` is name of the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing:

```
Import["C:\\Users\\TeM\\Desktop\\data.xlsx", {"Data"}][[1, Range[129, 159], {7, 13}]]
```

I get:

> {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}

which is what you want.

Comment: That's the syntax I have been looking for - thank you! The output seems to be ok, but it's blank data - I get {{, },{, },{, },....}. The data I'm trying to export from Excel are numbers, but they are computed, not entered manually, maybe that could be the problem? Got an idea how to solve it?

Comment: It's numbers,I thought that it shouldn't matter how was the data generated, I just mentioned it. I tried the same code line with "Formulas" instead of "Data", and it extracted the formulas that are on those exact positions, so it is well written, it just does not give the numbers, I really don't know why.

Comment: Wow, I've just now mistyped the number 1 /that should stand for sheet identificator, I think, right?/ as 2 and it worked. No idea why...

Answer (score 3):

You can also specify the sheets, rows and columns in `Import` (rather than importing the whole data and selecting specific rows and columns).

For example, for the following Excel workbook `"data.xlsx"` with two sheets

```
expdata1 = Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 200}, {j, CharacterRange["A", "Z"]}];
Export["data.xlsx", {{"Experiment 1" -> expdata1,
     "Experiment 2" -> {RandomReal[1,10]}}}, {{"Sheets"}}];
```

To get rows `129-139` and columns `7` and `13` from the first sheet you can use

```
imported = Import["data.xlsx", {"Data", 1, Range[129, 139], {7,13}}]
```

or

```
imported = Import["data.xlsx", {"Sheets", "Experiment 1", Range[129, 139], {7, 13}}]
```

to get

> {{"{129, \"G\"}", "{129, \"M\"}"}, {"{130, \"G\"}", 
>      "{130, \"M\"}"}, {"{131, \"G\"}", "{131, \"M\"}"}, {"{132, \"G\"}",
>       "{132, \"M\"}"}, {"{133, \"G\"}", 
>      "{133, \"M\"}"}, {"{134, \"G\"}", "{134, \"M\"}"}, {"{135, \"G\"}",
>       "{135, \"M\"}"}, {"{136, \"G\"}", 
>      "{136, \"M\"}"}, {"{137, \"G\"}", "{137, \"M\"}"}, {"{138, \"G\"}",
>       "{138, \"M\"}"}, {"{139, \"G\"}", "{139, \"M\"}"}};

```
MatrixForm@imported
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Can you maybe split it up in multiple parts? i.e.

```
a = Import["....xlsx",{"Data"}]
b = Transpose[a[[1,129;;159,{7,13}]]]
```

or something like that?